# Why simple Django iterate table has memory leak

Tags: django, memory-leaks

I have a simple Django project to iterate a table, which is illustrated in following:

```
from myprojectmodule import models 

if __name__ == '__main__':
  if not settings.configured:
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')
  django.setup()


  for item in models.mytable.objects.all():
    print item
```

It has memory leak like followings:

```
    Warning:  160 bytes lost at 0x65bc980, allocated by T@0 at 
        @     0x7f5f0327d075  my_malloc
        @     0x7f5f0321a95e  mysql_options
        @     0x7f5f0321dfa5  set_connect_attributes
        @     0x7f5f0321c1df  mysql_real_connect
        @     0x7f5f192f281b  _mysql_ConnectionObject_Initialize
        @           0x49ccdf  wrap_init
    Memory lost: 17536 bytes in 15 chunks
```

How to avoid it? What is missing to avoid the memory leak.

Comment: Any chance this might be due to the missing quote in front of "myproject.settings"?

Comment: I corrected the typo. thank you. Sure that's not the reason for observed memory leak.